# Probability of being late to bus

Tags: probability, statistics, regression

Bob takes a bus everyday to get to his school. The bus takes off exactly at 7.00 everyday. Here is when bob arrives to the bus stop:

day one: 6.58
day two: 6.55
day three: 6.58
day four: 7.02
day five: 7.10

Questions:
- What is the probability that bob will be late on the next day?
- Would your answer to the first question differ if 7.10 was instead 8.10?
- Would your answer to the first question differ if the times on the first and the fifth days were swapped?

Edit:
Assume that the data is normally distributed.

My comments:
These questions might not have a single definite answer, but I'd still like to see your reasoning. The problem I guess boils down to the following logic question: If bob gets to the stop later day after the day, would it be more logical to expect that bob will be even later on the next time, or will be there approximately somewhere around the mean value.
Thanks

Comment: This is not clear.  Are we meant to guess a probability distribution from those five data points?  Five is a very small sample..any guess would most likely be quite wrong.

Comment: The question is, how would you like to model Bob's behavior.  With 5 data points we could make an argument for just about any distribution.  I would probably use an exponential, or a log-normal.  These allows for a long right tail.  But, if Bob is a human and not a machine (or a random variable).  After missing the bus 2 days in a row, he make make an effort to get to the bus stop earlier the next day.

Comment: How would you proceed if the data was normally distributed?

Comment: In addition to normal distribution, if you also assume that each day's observation is **independent** then the order doesn't matter.  Estimate the mean and variance.

Comment: Then I see that it is possible to solve it using the normal distribution. I thought linear or polynomial regression could let us find the optimal distribution

Comment: I posted an answer but admins promptly deleted it claiming I am not providing an answer... Maybe because they did not understand it? I think this is more of a riddle than a real math problem. After going to school for five consecutive days, the next day would be a Saturday, when there is no school. So my answer is zero. I feel most people would agree this is the answer that makes the most sense (e.g. it explains the ridiculously small sample size) and probably what the person who originally wrote this question was after.